# Windows start/jump bar icons are too small

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, start-menu, windows-10-preview

I just installed windows 10 and everything looks fine and nicely scaled, except for the jump bar. The icons don't fill the complete height of the bar, and look a bit lost...

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

PS, the Windows 8.1 comparison:

[image]

Comment: About the icons, that is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: Are You sure? I just added the 8.1 version, which looks alot better. Why would they do that?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is how it looks like on Windows 10. I have installed Windows 10 on two notebooks.

Comment: yeah, this sucks. Submit feedback here: https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/

Answer (score 1):

[StartIsBack](http://startisback.com/) has an option to restore pre Windows 10 taskbar icon size. The application is not free, but has 30 days trial.

[image]

P.S.: I'm not it's author.